# Extracting origin properties (metadata) from a word document in R

Tags: r, ms-word, metadata

I have hundreds of word documents (.docx) that were sent to me for analysis and I´m struggling to find a way to extract the Origin metadata. I would like to know the author's name, content created and the date last saved for each document - please note that these are properties that you can check under "details" separator when you use the mouse right-click on the word document and you select "properties". I would like to have an have a dataframe, a list or something similar with:
[1] "document.name" "authors.name" "content.created" "date.lastsaved"
[2] "document.name2" "authors.name2" "content.created2" "date.lastsaved2"

Does anyone have a nice solution for the problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this:

```
setwd("/Desktop/docs") # set directory to wherever your docx files are

file.info(list.files(getwd())) # obtain file info for docs in folder
```

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't give me the "Origin creation" date only seen in the metadata. I got the files from someone else, and I lost the "original" properties such as the date of creation when I copied to my computer so I need to use the metadata instead

Comment: I see yes, copying might modify the created date. I am afraid there is no straight forward solution in R (that I know off) so perhaps a command line function would be better suitable.

Comment: e.g., try `$ GetFileInfo filename.doc` in your terminal (mac)

Comment: meanwhile, I've found this: https://exceleratorbi.com.au/extract-word-metadata-with-excel-vba/    it can be a solution using excel instead of R